# Nested form and namespaced engine in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, models

I'm building a Rails Engine and everything is namespaced. For example, the models can be accessed from `Wanker::MyModel`

For the first time in this project I want to use the automatic form system provided by Rails. I want to create a `Wanker::Company` followed by a linked table named `Wanker::CompanyDetail`

```
<%= form_for @company, url: company_index_path(@company) do |f| %>

<div>
<%= f.label :name %><br />
<%= f.text_field :name, autocomplete: "off" %>
</div>

<br />

<%= f.fields_for @company_detail do |d| %>

    <%= d.label :address %><br />
    <%= d.text_field :address, autocomplete: "off" %>
    <br />
```

Then I save it in the `create` method

```
@company = Wanker::Company.new(params[:company].permit!)

if @company.save
```

In a normal case that should work, but here I got a big error.

> NameError in Wanker::CompanyController#create 
>   uninitialized constant CompanyDetail

How can I specify that this `CompanyDetail` model is in `Wanker` namespace ? Thank you ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few more hours I gave up. I changed my models to be more explicit to Rails

```
has_one :company_detail, :class_name => 'Wanker::CompanyDetail'
```

So it changed the error

```
Wanker::CompanyDetail(#70213086467980) expected, got ActionController::Parameters(#70213107743520)
```

I tried to get around it by manipulating the datas but it seems like it's completely impossible to populate this `company_details` table automatically.

My only viable solution is to cancel this automatism when I save the datas. I split it into 2 separated system.

```
@company_detail = Wanker::CompanyDetail.new(params[:company][:company_detail].permit!)
params[:company].delete(:company_detail)

@company = Wanker::Company.new(params[:company].permit!)

@company.user_id = current_user.id

if @company.save && @company_detail.save

    @company_detail.company_id = @company.id
    @company_detail.save

    flash[:notice] = "Your company has been added"


else

    flash[:errors] = @company.errors.full_messages + @company_detail.errors.full_messages

    redirect_to(:back)

end
```

Hope this helps anyway.